# C# API POST Request

Tags: c#, html, api, rest, testing

I'm trying to post to an API using C#.

Here is some documentation on the API: http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api/accessing

Here is what I have so far:

```
string url = "https://example.testrail.com//index.php?/miniapi/add_result/1&key=19e73cdd99fbad172d3523b13d1c8c8f";

HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url))as HttpWebRequest;
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

My question is how can I pass in a Status_id of 1 and a comment of "Test" and then post to the API?

Comment: Consider using `HttpClient`, which is much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `GetRequestStream` method on your `req` object, and write the post parameters to that